# Div не принимает высоту вложенного в него контента

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

Подскажите, есть div (`footer-top`), он `0` по высоте, хотя в нем много других divов и прочего контента.

Он разве не должен становиться той высоты, какая высота его контента?

```css
.footer-top {
  padding-top: 70px;
  height: 270px;
}

.logo-footer, .our-studio, .stay-in-touch {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: calc(33% - 30px);
  height: 200px;
}

.logo-footer-img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 128px;
  background-image: url(../img/logo-footer.png);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.logo-footer p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.our-studio h6 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.our-studio p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.our-studio p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/our-studio-bg.png);
  width: 14px;
  height: 19px;
}

.footer-phone {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

p.footer-phone:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/footer-phone.png);
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}

.stay-in-touch h6 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.stay-input {
  background: none;
  width: 201px;
  height: 45px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.stay-button {
  height: 45px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.stay-input, .stay-button {
  float: left;
}

.stay-input::-moz-placeholder { 
  opacity: 0.75;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.stay-input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  opacity: 0.75;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
}

.stay-in-touch form {
  height: 45px;
}

.links {
  height: 35px;
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.links-ul {
  height: 35px;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.links-item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.link-a {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  display: block;
}

.li1 {
  background-image: url(../img/li1.png);
}

.li2 {
  background-image: url(../img/li2.png);
}

.li3 {
  background-image: url(../img/li3.png);
}

.li4 {
  background-image: url(../img/li4.png);
}

.li5 {
  background-image: url(../img/li5.png);
}

.li6 {
  background-image: url(../img/li6.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-top">
  <div class="logo-footer">
    <div class="logo-footer-img"></div>
    <p>lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh elit. Duis sed odio sit amet auctror a ornare odio non mauris vitae erat in elit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="our-studio">
    <h6>OUR STUDIO</h6> 
    <p>Ruko cucruk, Jl. Radio luar dalem jos No.12 - 13, Kalideres - Jakarta Barat 11480 - Indonesia</p>
    <p class="footer-phone">(+62) 21-2224 3333</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stay-in-touch">
    <h6>STAY IN TOUCH</h6>
    <form>
      <input type="email" name="email-newsletter" placeholder="Subscribe our newsletter" class="stay-input">
      <input type="image" src="img/newsletter-button.png" name="imagebutton" class="stay-button">
    </form>
    <div class="links">
      <ul class="links-ul">
        <li class="links-item li1"><a href="#" class="link-a"></a></li>
        <li class="links-item li2"><a href="#" class="link-a"></a></li>
        <li class="links-item li3"><a href="#" class="link-a"></a></li>
        <li class="links-item li4"><a href="#" class="link-a"></a></li>
        <li class="links-item li5"><a href="#" class="link-a"></a></li>
        <li class="links-item li6"><a href="#" class="link-a"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы написали глупость. "Есть машина (черная) не заводится, хотя пассажиры сидят внутри".

Больше деталей, примеры кода.

Comment: А по-моему здесь все очень понятно....

Comment: соответствующий CSS забыли

Comment: вот как-то так здесь css добавляется

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d0vc3n  И что Вас не устраивает. Высота есть.

Comment: Нет, он 0 по высоте

Comment: =))))))))))) нет так нет)))) `.footer-top {
  ...
  height: 270px;
}`

Comment: Это я задал его вручную, в пикселях. Обязательно задавать? Если не задавать, он сам не растягивается по высоте вложенного контента?

Comment: так зачем же вы в вопрсое выложили код с заданой высотой? Чтобы запутать остальных ? ))

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer-top {
  padding-top: 70px;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden; // заставит контейнер "растянуться" чтобы вместить внутренние float-элементы
}
```

[Clear или overflow:hidden — очистка всего потока или создание контекста форматирования?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/48383/)

Второй вариант.
Добавить внутрь div.footer-top div `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`, который отключит обтекание и тоже "потянет" размеры контенера. Тут вы ещё увидите, что содержимое внутренних плавающих div вылазит за их границы, которые вы назначили `height: 200px;`

Comment: спасибо! первый и единственный дельный совет по этому вопросу.